# How can I contact another YouTuber?

Tags: youtube

I need to contact another YouTuber for a business purpose.

But this YouTuber doesn’t have anything in their “About” section (no Business Inquiry Email). And YouTube removed the “About > Send Message” button 6 months ago.

And I already know about "Friends". But to do that, you have to (somehow) send the YouTuber a hyperlink "invitation" - and so I come back to my original problem.

And I know I can already leave a comment, but I don’t want to do that. They might not see it and also, it’s public.

They are not showing any kind of social media links or anything like that.
So, how can I contact another YouTuber?

I'm a Premium member. I know there is something called a Partner account, and a Creator account. I'm wondering if me having one of those would make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

simply put, you can't contact such user who didn't provide Business Inquiry Email

> Send & receive messages
>
> As of July 9, 2018, the ability to send,
> receive, or read private messages in Creator Studio is no longer
> available. We made this change because this feature was not widely
> used, and will allow us to focus on the features and tools that matter
> most to you. All private messages have therefore been deleted from
> Creator Studio and anywhere else on YouTube.
>
> Business Inquiry Emails You can still receive and send email messages
> to fellow users on the platform using Business Inquiry Emails (visible
> on Desktop only) when provided by the channel owner on the "About" tab
> of their channel.
>
> If a Business Inquiry Email is provided, select "View Email Address". If you don’t see a Business Inquiry Email, that means that the channel owner didn’t provide one.
>
> **[https://support.google.com/youtube/](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57955?hl=en)**

---

- partner account = Partner Program - **https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851**
- creator account = Creator Studio - **https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6060318**